# How to set up a running total in a table

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
  |-----+-----+
1 |  A  |  B  |
  |-----+-----+
2 | Num | Sum |
3 |  1  |  1  |
4 |  2  |  3  |
5 |  3  |  6  |
6 |  4  | 10  |
7 |  5  | 15  |
8 |  6  | 21  |
  |-----+-----+
```

This example we will have our marker on "B6"

If this would be a table in excel and i would like to select the rows from "B3 - B6" is there anyway to do this automatic with table references?

I have only found [@Sum] to select the row in current line, it would select (B6).

And you can also use [Sum] to select every row in current column, so it would select "B3 - B8"

But what if i would like to select every row from where i am above me, "B6 - B3", or the other way around "B6 - B8" underneath me?

Everything else seems to be possible, and do it manually  by hand takes a lot of time.

Comment: Ctrl+shift+up / down?

Answer (score 1):

I'm interpreting your question to mean how do you create a formula using structured referencing to accomplish, for example, a running total.

There may be other methods, but you can use the `INDEX` function.

For example, to show a running total in the `SUM` column (assuming that `NUM` & `SUM` are the Headers):

```
B3: =SUM(INDEX([Num],1):[@Num])
```

[image]

And, for the reverse (adding from the bottom up):

```
=SUM(INDEX([Num],COUNT([Num])):[@Num])
```

[image]

*In the formulas above, note that the `column_num` argument of the `INDEX` function, being optional with only a single column, has been omitted.*

For other variations of from the current row to some previous or subsequent row, that is not the first or last, you can use other variations of the `INDEX` function.

Given your real example, and the desire to insert extra columns, you still use a variation of the `SUM(INDEX(…` formula, but you need to both convert your column references to absolute references, and also return a `0` if the **Account** does not match the **Header** row.

So, given your example table, you would use the following formulas

```
E2:  =SUM(INDEX((Table1[[Account]:[Account]]=Table1[[#Headers],[Home]])*Table1[[Transaction]:[Transaction]],N(IF(1,SEQUENCE(ROW()-ROW(Table1[#Headers]),,1,1)))))
```

and fill across up to but **Not Including** the totals column

If you then select and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> for each formula in Row 2, it will fill down the rest of the column.

*If you do not have the `SEQUENCE` function and the formula returns a `#NAME!` error, try:

```
=SUM(INDEX((Table1[[Account]:[Account]]=Table1[[#Headers],[Saved]])*Table1[[Transaction]:[Transaction]],N(IF(1,ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1,1):INDEX($A:$A,ROW()-ROW(Table1[#Headers])))))))
```

For the Totals Column, which is an unfiltered total

```
=SUM(INDEX(Table1[[Transaction]:[Transaction]],1):Table1[@[Transaction]:[Transaction]])
```

[image]

- Since we are using Absolute references, when you insert a column, the references won't change.
- Because the `Total` column has a different formula than the others, and is at the end of the table, if you want to add account columns you'll need to insert them rather than add them onto the end.

Comment: A real example can be found https://1drv.ms/x/s!AhhNiAMJ9mFwoC7jLCLui5L1dr3Z and as i already have told is it in the tables where it is "Home/Car/Vacation/Saved" as i can't expand the table without edit those post manually.

Comment: @Whiskey. See my edit

Comment: I have try to apply this to my sheet but it was very hard to get it working, have never work whit index, do you have any example sheet?

Comment: @Whiskey What do you mean ***hard to get working***?  The `INDEX` function is well documented in Excel Help.  Use the Formula Evaluation tool.

Comment: As i have hard time understand how you use the formula, and as i don't understand if fully its more easy to see it from a real example to understand it.

Comment: @Whiskey I don't have a worksheet to upload.  What happened when you entered the formula into the appropriate cell of your worksheet, as I suggested?

Comment: It seems like i can't get the syntax right, that's why i asked for a sheet where i know it is so ether the syntax is wrong or i just misunderstand ow to apply it and that is for both formulas.

Comment: The answer for this question would be "=SUM.IF(INDEX([Account];1):[@Transaction]; "Home";INDEX([Transaction];1):[@Transaction])" and so on :)